# Function param javascript scope

Tags: javascript, scope, parameters

I have this piece of code

```
function showOpenMaps(position,located){
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        cache:true
    });
    jQuery.getScript("http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js")
        .done(function (script, textStatus) {
            $(".geocoder").show();
            $("#map_canvas").html("");
            var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
            var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
            var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.longitude, p....
        }
```

My param position is not defined but it's ok outside the `getScript` call. Any ideas? Is it scope related?

Comment: How about showing us all the relevant code? Especially if the problem is with `position`, it's a bad idea to crop the code there.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on closures and variable scope for anonymous functions.

Comment: `var position = ...position.coords.longitude`. You seem to have two `position` variables. One from closure, one from local scope.

Comment: It's just in that line that position it's not defined.

Comment: @NestorPs: In fact, it *is defined* (`var position`), otherwise it would refer to the function parameter. It only was not yet assigned to.

Comment: Yes I got it. I've changed my param position to position_geo and know it's working. Thanks guys